Area size generated by editor behind legend elements is missing when exporting PNG with QGIS Layout
I use QGIS Version 3.28.3-Firenze.
In a QGIS Layout, I add the sum of area to each class in the legend via the editor.
I use the following expression:
@symbol_label 
||  ' (' 
||  round(aggregate(@layer, 'sum', $area, filter:= "column that is used for classification"=@symbol_label)/10000,0)
|| 
' ha' ||  ')'

The result is fine:

But when I export the Layout, the generated sum of area is not exported.

How can I fix the problem? I really would like to export the maps with the sum of the area behind the legend elements.

Works perfectly on version 3.20.3.
